# Issue with dereferencing of pointers

Tags: c, pointers, struct, dereference

I get an error when trying to assign a value to a pointer.

I have defined 2 structs:

```
typedef struct {
    struct player *next; //pointers
    struct player *prev;
} player;

typedef struct {
    player onMe; //object
} field;
```

later in the code, I create an instance of the struct "player p" and try to use it:
fields[][] is an array that holds structs of the type field.

```
fields[p.x][p.y].onMe = *(p.next);
(*p.prev).next = &p.next;
```

in these cases i get "error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type"
I also tried (&p.next) but has the same result.

```
fields[x][y].onMe.prev = (&p);
```

in this case i get "warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]"

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't declare `struct player` anywhere so the definition of the struct is incomplete. Try

```
typedef struct player_s {
    struct player_s *prev;
    struct player_s *next;
} player;
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that `struct player` is incomplete type. You declare `player` type with `typedef`. But you've used `struct player` as its part, which is not defined now or anywhere else.

You should use something like

```
typedef struct player {
    struct player *next; //pointers
    struct player *prev;
} player;
```

Comment: i'm not allowed to vote. tried to vote up but it requires 15 points but i'm new to this site (just reading so far)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that you assign another struct A pointer to the *array.onMe* one.
By the way, why you assign the ptr address to another ptr? May be you want assign the address a ptr pointered to to the other pointer, like below:

```
(*p.prev).next = p.next
```